# How to put square sized ad on layout

Tags: android

I want to put square ad on my app layout i tried my best but not got any information regarding square ad i am adding image also below please give me some advice [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy4Jn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConstraintLayout with app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" />
```

Comment: I want to add admob ad like that image is that possible with this?

Comment: You could put whatever view you want. app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio works to any view which is placed inside ConstraintLayout

Comment: but how what kind of ad it is banner, native?